# JsonConvert PreserveReferencesHandling.None not Working

Tags: c#-4.0, json.net

I have an object that I need to serialize and return to my javascript. My object is something like this:

```
public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Publisher> AssociatedPublisher { get; set; }
    public List<Publisher> NonAssociatedPublisher { get; set; }
}
```

If I populate both `AssociatedPublisher` and `NonAssociatePublisher` with one, and the same `Publisher` in list then I do

```
var b = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(book, new JsonSerializerSettings { PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.None });
```

When I inspect `var b` it always has the `NonAssociatedPublisher` serialized as:

```
NonAssociatedPublisher
     |
     |-----[0]
            |
            |----$ref: "3"
```

What I want is the full object, not just the reference. It seems the PreserveReferencesHandling.None is not working or I misunderstand its use?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry that I have to answer my own question. The problem is that both `AssociatedPublisher` and `NonAssociatedPublisher` are from EF and they're marked (IsReference=true).

The solution I came up with was to make my own class for `AssociatedPublisher` and `NonAssociatedPublisher` instead of using the ones from EF.